# Retrieve Journey Name using ampscript or ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, variable-names, bind-variable

Does anyone know how to retrieve the Journey Name using either ampscript or ssjs? I want to populate the name inside of a variable when the email is sent through a journey? Something similar to grabbing the email name using %%EmailName_%%.

Comment: I was able to do some research. I was looking for a personalization string for the Journey Builder to plug in the name of the Journey. Unfortunately, there is none. I could call it through an api call but that is a lot of work just to get the name. Plus it will not be scale-able to pull the name out from other journeys. Can anyone think of a different method to grab the Journey Name during a send of the email?

Comment: What about Query? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you Selim for responding. This seems like a good method but I think you can only query the data views of the journey after the email is deployed. I need something that will evaluate the Journey Name and plug it into the html before the email is sent to the customer.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, the only method I can suggest is writing them into an excel file manually to import them in a data extension.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The purpose was for my boss to push the campaign name through Analytics when a person clicks a CTA. I suggested that we put the campaign name in the Data Extension instead. It would be easier to pull the Name from their than to manually fill the Data or jump through hoops to grab it from the Journey.