# Personalization strings

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, parameters, web-analytics-connector

Is there any personalization string that brings the name of the journey?
I need to automatize the utm_campaign in Parameter Manager but it only allows me to use the Email name. Is there any trick to change it for the journey name instead? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, Journey Name is not available in email context: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247849/retrieve-journey-name-using-ampscript-or-ssjs

Answer (score -1):

If the journey name is a fixed value for a particular audience, you might consider storing it in a data extension or attribute set that is accessible during email sends. You could then use AMPscript or a lookup to retrieve the journey name from the data extension or attribute set.

Comment: This seems to go against Lukas's comment. If this is an actual answer (not generated by AI), you need to go into greater detail.